# External JavaScript to hide/show menu not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and stuck in the first program. When I use the internal JavaScript it is working but not from the external JavaScript file.
JavaScript is not working here. Here I want to use JavaScript to hide and show the menu item, the button in the last element is only for testing.

```
showMenu(){
  var x = document.getElementById('mainmenu');
  if(x.style.display == "none"){
    x.style.display="block";
  }
  else{
    x.style.display="none";
  }
}
```

css for the html

```
body{
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#topcontact{
  background-color: teal;
  margin: -16px 0;
}
#topcontact p{
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
}

header{
  width:100%;
  background-color: white;
}
ul{
  flex-flow: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
}
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
ul li:hover{
  background: lightgrey;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.toggle{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #001f44;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .toggle{
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  ul li{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

and this is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Welcome to JS page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="mainmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Education Materials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonshowing').style.display='block'">Show Data</button>
    <div id="buttonshowing" style="display: none;">you clicked show data</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/mainjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please reduce code to contain only the parts which are problematic for you. This way question will be more clear for others. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have included the file incorrectly. You are missing a `dot`, which represents the current directory.

Use this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/mainjs.js"></script>`

and always declare a function with a `function` keyword:

```js
function showMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById('mainmenu');
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. dot was not the problem but I found a simple mistake i.e semicolon ; after the function. Anyway thank you

Comment: @EverestBeauties Best of luck! :)